# Copying rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy all of the columns of a row, but not have to specify every column. I am aware of the syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html but I see no way to ignore a column.

For my example, I am trying to copy all the columns of a row to a new row, except for the primary key.

Is there a way to do that without having to write the query with every field in it?

Answer (score 16):

If your `id` or primary key column is an `auto_increment` you can use a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
AS 
SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE id='7'; 
UPDATE temp_table SET id='100' WHERE id='7';
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```

so in this way you can copy all data in row id='7' and then assign
new value '100' (or whatever value falls above the range of your current auto_increment value in source_table).

Edit: Mind the ; after the statments :)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. For anybody else trying to do this with php, remember each sql statement has to go as a single `mysql_query()`

Comment: Setting `id` to zero also works. On `INSERT`, an `auto_increment` column with the value `0` is inserted as whatever the next value should be.

Comment: Works best as a stored routine.

Comment: How do we get the last inserted id from this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to list out the columns that you want to select if you aren't selecting them all.  Copy/Paste is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP script that I wrote to do this, it will assume that your first col is your auto increment.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 1; $i < mysql_num_fields($res); $i++) {
     $col_names .= mysql_field_name($res, $i).", ";
 }
 $col_names = substr($col_names, 0, -2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (".$col_names.") SELECT ".$col_names." FROM table_name WHERE condition ";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the columns you have to keep the entries in order. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `Email`, `UserName`) VALUES
(1, 'so@so.com', 'StackOverflow')
```

Would work but

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES
('so@so.com', 'StackOverflow')
```

would place the Email at the ID column so it's no good.

Try writing the columns once like:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `UserName`) VALUES
('so@so.com', 'StackOverflow'),
('so2@so.com', 'StackOverflow2'),
('so3@so.com', 'StackOverflow3'),
etc...
```

I think there's a limit to how many rows you can insert with that method though.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only limit on the number of rows you can insert with that method is the MySQL packet size.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible.

But it's easy to get the column list and just delete which one you don't want copied this process can also be done through code etc.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the table to a new one, then delete the column you don't want. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that since you want to omit the primary key that it is an `auto_increment` column and you want MySQL to autogenerate the next value in the sequence.

Given that, assuming that you do not need to do bulk inserts via the insert into ... select from method, the following will work for single/multi record inserts:

insert into mytable (null, 'a', 'b', 'c');

Where the first column is your `auto_incremented` primary key and the others are your other columns on the table. When MySQL sees a null (or 0) for an `auto_incremented` column it will automatically replace the null with the next valid value (see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) for more information). This functionality can be disabled by disabling the `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` sql mode described in that link.

Let me know if you have any questions.

-Dipin

Comment: "I want to copy all of the columns of a row, BUT NOT HAVE TO SPECIFY EVERY COLUMN"  ?

Comment: When it comes to insert statements in SQL the column names list is the part that comes before the VALUES keyword. Given that I work with SQL, I had taken the question to mean that the OP wanted to avoid having to list out the column names and not that he/she wanted to avoid specifying the *value* of each column also (which, as noted by others, is not possible as it would be akin to someone trying to store a value in a variable in another language without actually writing the assignment statement).