# How to copy a row and insert in same table with a autoincrement field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, copy

In MySQL I am trying to copy a row with an **autoincrement** `column ID=1` and **insert** the data into same table as a new row with `column ID=2`.

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: Related questions: [Duplicate / Copy records in the same MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729489/711006), [In MySQL, can I copy one row to insert into the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4039748/711006)

Answer (score 483, accepted):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from your_table
where id = 1
```

where `c1, c2, ...` are all the columns except `id`. If you want to explicitly insert with an `id` of 2 then include that in your INSERT column list and your SELECT:

```
insert into your_table (id, c1, c2, ...)
select 2, c1, c2, ...
from your_table
where id = 1
```

You'll have to take care of a possible duplicate `id` of 2 in the second case of course.

Comment: You could programatically get then names of the columns using INFORMATION_SCHEMA ... I wonder if you could do it as a sub-query and some string functions? Hmmm...

Comment: @Yzmir: You'd end up having to use dynamic SQL and that would usually require building a stored procedure. Seems like more trouble than it's worth when you should have a list of column names handy anyway.

Comment: Agreed...from my experience once you go Stored Procedure you don't go back - you're married to that database now and just adds to the costs whenever you want to change.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, you make it sound like marriage is inherently a bad thing. :)

Comment: when trying to insert without id  : it gives error : primary key violation . when trying to insert with id  : it gives error :  you cant directly insert vwith primary key . either way i cant do it .

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail: Seems to work fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1454/1 . The first error means that you're somehow getting duplicate PK values, I've never seen the second error.

Comment: The ID field is auto-increment, right? So, you shouldn't select `2`, you should select `null` for the ID. Then, it will be populated with the next available ID.

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly But they wanted to explicitly use an `id` of `2`. If they wanted to use the auto-increment values then leaving the `id` out completely (`insert into t (c1, c2, ...) select c1, c2, ...`) would probably be better than trying to use `null`; some databases would be upset by the `null`, no need to acquire unnecessary bad habits.

Comment: How to add one custom value in the column with all other copied fields?

Comment: @CrackIt Put a constant in the `select`: `select 2, c1, SOME_CUSTOM_VALUE, c3, ...`

Comment: @muistooshort Let me try

Answer (score 63):

IMO, the best seems to use sql statements only to copy that row, while at the same time only referencing the columns you must and want to change.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table ENGINE=MEMORY

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=1;
UPDATE temp_table SET id=0; /* Update other values at will. */

INSERT INTO your_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
DROP TABLE temp_table;
```

See also [av8n.com - How to Clone an SQL Record](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/clone-sql-record.htm#sec-nontrivial)

Benefits:

- The SQL statements 2 mention only the fields that need to be changed during the cloning process. They do not know about – or care about – other fields. The other fields just go along for the ride, unchanged. This makes the SQL statements easier to write, easier to read, easier to maintain, and more extensible.
- Only ordinary MySQL statements are used. No other tools or programming languages are required.
- A fully-correct record is inserted in `your_table` in one atomic operation.

Comment: It seams, that this nice trick (I liked it, but it did not work for me) does not work on tables that contain TEXT/VARCHAR columns. I tried it and got: (1163): The used table type doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns. That of course limits the usage on MySQL very much! Might be, that in the future these limits are lifted or on other db-systems it does work out, but for now it is really to limited.

Comment: I really like the clever use of temporary table. So useful for tables with a ton of columns!

Comment: Looks nice, but when I run the first query in MySQL, I get `Error Code: 1113. A table must have at least 1 column`.

Comment: Best answer for a lot of columns.
But `SET id=NULL` may cause an error `Column 'id' cannot be null`.
Should be replaced by
`UPDATE temp_table SET id = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 as id FROM your_table);`

Comment: @physicalattraction you need to make sure the first two lines are one statement.

Comment: @Modder - or `SET id = 0` - from [Trig's comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918543/199364).

Comment: I liked this, but Null threw an error for me on MySql 5.5. As per ToolmakerSteve, 0 worked. From another answer: When MySQL sees a null (or 0) for an auto_incremented column it will automatically replace the null with the next valid value. Not sure why 5.5 threw an error.

Answer (score 17):

Say the table is `user(id, user_name, user_email)`.

You can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO user (SELECT NULL,user_name, user_email FROM user WHERE id = 1)
```

Comment: You should **always** specify the column names when using INSERT, otherwise you will get strange and interesting bugs when your schema changes.

Comment: Strange and interesting, indeed. :D

Comment: Does not work with sqlite. 
`Result: near "SELECT": syntax error`

Comment: Giving error in postgresql : `ERROR: null value in column "id" `

Answer (score 15):

This helped and it supports a BLOB/TEXT columns.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
AS
SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE id=2;
UPDATE temp_table SET id=NULL WHERE id=2;
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
USE source_table;
```

Comment: In what way this is better than other answers here?

Comment: I think it's pretty good if you have a table with 100 of fields. Except there might be a not null constraint on the id which makes it fail

Comment: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: This is much better if you have a table with 100s of columns.

Comment: Isn't this what parvus said, years earlier?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, the other apparently doesn't support "BLOB/TEXT columns."

Comment: I had a primary key which was autoincremented, so i also had to use: INSERT INTO test_table (SELECT null,txt FROM test_table) to use NULL to pad out the primary key else i got errors.

Answer (score 9):

For a quick, clean solution that doesn't require you to name columns, you can use a prepared statement as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23964285/292677

If you need a complex solution so you can do this often, you can use this procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `duplicateRows`(_schemaName text, _tableName text, _whereClause text, _omitColumns text)
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  SELECT IF(TRIM(_omitColumns) <> '', CONCAT('id', ',', TRIM(_omitColumns)), 'id') INTO @omitColumns;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_schema = _schemaName AND table_name = _tableName AND FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME,@omitColumns) = 0 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION INTO @columns;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', _tableName, '(', @columns, ')',
  'SELECT ', @columns, 
  ' FROM ', _schemaName, '.', _tableName, ' ',  _whereClause);

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
END
```

You can run it with:

```
CALL duplicateRows('database', 'table', 'WHERE condition = optional', 'omit_columns_optional');
```

Examples

```
duplicateRows('acl', 'users', 'WHERE id = 200'); -- will duplicate the row for the user with id 200
duplicateRows('acl', 'users', 'WHERE id = 200', 'created_ts'); -- same as above but will not copy the created_ts column value    
duplicateRows('acl', 'users', 'WHERE id = 200', 'created_ts,updated_ts'); -- same as above but also omits the updated_ts column
duplicateRows('acl', 'users'); -- will duplicate all records in the table
```

DISCLAIMER: This solution is only for someone who will be repeatedly duplicating rows in many tables, often. It could be dangerous in the hands of a rogue user.

Answer (score 6):

If you're able to use MySQL Workbench, you can do this by right-clicking the row and selecting 'Copy row', and then right-clicking the empty row and selecting 'Paste row', and then changing the ID, and then clicking 'Apply'.

Copy the row:

[image]

Paste the copied row into the blank row:

[image]

Change the ID:

[image]

Apply:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into MyTable(field1, field2, id_backup)
    select field1, field2, uniqueId from MyTable where uniqueId = @Id;
```

Comment: How is this better than other answers here?

Comment: @smar imo it's cleaner to understand

Comment: It guarantees that values are inserted in their respective columns.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of great answers here. Below is a sample of the stored procedure that I wrote to accomplish this task for a Web App that I am developing:

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create Temporary Table
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM <YourTable> WHERE Id = Id

--To trigger the auto increment
UPDATE #tempTable SET Id = NULL 

--Update new data row in #tempTable here!

--Insert duplicate row with modified data back into your table
INSERT INTO <YourTable> SELECT * FROM #tempTable

-- Drop Temporary Table
DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Comment: in the current version of MariaDB/MySQL  setting id=null gives #1048 - Column 'id' cannot be null,  setting id=0 works;

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass in '0' as the value for the column to auto-increment, the correct value will be used when the record is created. This is so much easier than temporary tables.

Source:
[Copying rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229998/copying-rows-in-mysql) 
(see the second comment, by TRiG, to the first solution, by Lore)

Comment: This method works with newer MySQL versions when NULL is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a variation of what mu is too short posted:

```
INSERT INTO something_log
SELECT NULL, s.*
FROM something AS s
WHERE s.id = 1;
```

As long as the tables have identical fields (excepting the auto increment on the log table), then this works nicely.

Since I use stored procedures whenever possible (to make life easier on other programmers who aren't too familiar with databases), this solves the problem of having to go back and update procedures every time you add a new field to a table.

It also ensures that if you add new fields to a table they will start appearing in the log table immediately without having to update your database queries (unless of course you have some that set a field explicitly)

**Warning:** You will want to make sure to add any new fields to both tables at the same time so that the field order stays the same... otherwise you will start getting odd bugs. If you are the only one that writes database interfaces AND you are very careful then this works nicely. Otherwise, stick to naming all of your fields.

**Note:** On second thought, unless you are working on a solo project that you are sure won't have others working on it stick to listing all field names explicitly and update your log statements as your schema changes. This shortcut probably is not worth the long term headache it can cause... especially on a production system.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `dbMyDataBase`.`tblMyTable` 
(
    `IdAutoincrement`, 
    `Column2`, 
    `Column3`, 
    `Column4` 
) 

SELECT 
    NULL,  
    `Column2`, 
    `Column3`, 
    'CustomValue' AS Column4 
FROM `dbMyDataBase`.`tblMyTable` 
WHERE `tblMyTable`.`Column2` = 'UniqueValueOfTheKey' 
; 
/* mySQL 5.6 */
```

Comment: Try adding some more detailed explanation, or how this expands on the other answers

Comment: This is actually the right answer.  Yes, it's terse, but anyone who understands SQL should "get" it.  I even used REPLACE as part of my statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (SELECT null,txt FROM test_table)
```

Every time you run this query, This will insert all the rows again with new ids. values in your table and will increase exponentially.

I used a table with two columns i.e id and txt and id is auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same feature but I don't use MySQL. I wanted to copy ALL the fields except of course the primary key (id). This was a one shot query, not to be used in any script or code.

I found my way around with PL/SQL but I'm sure any other SQL IDE would do. I did a basic

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id=42;
```

Then export it to a SQL file where I could find the

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, ... , col42) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3, ..., 42);
```

I just edited it and used it :

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, ... , col42) 
VALUES (mysequence.nextval, 2, 3, ..., 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into your_table(col1,col2,col3) select  col1+1,col2,col3  from your_table where col1=1;
```

Note:make sure that after increment the new value of col1 is not duplicate entry if col1 is primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `temp_table` LIKE source_table;
DELETE FROM `purchasing2` ;
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM source_table where columnid = 2;
ALTER TABLE temp_table MODIFY id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE temp_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
UPDATE temp_table SET id=NULL ;
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
DROP TEMPORARY  TABLE IF EXISTS  temp_table ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Dump the row you want to sql and then use the generated SQL, less the ID column to import it back in.

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer better.

Comment: Whilst brief this is the technique I use. I believe OP is referring to Script->Table as Insert and Script->Table as Select in this answer  (SSMS gui commands).  And once you remove the PK/IDENTITY column from the produced SQL, this forms the base of a decent clone query.