# Insert Rows with using the result from a group of select best way to do it

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an array of tags inserted in my database, and I need to insert them in another table with `itemID` and `tagID`.

The thing is that i don't have the `tagID` - instead I have a `TagName` with the name. I need to get the `tagID` so I can insert it afterward, but I'm wondering if this is possible to achieve in one single query.

I mean search for the name, then get its `tagID` and then insert it the array, or even inserting them one by one would work.

Comment: unless the TagNames are unique you will get back many possible TagIDs when you try to get it.  If the Names are unique it begs the question why isnt it the PK?  Otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: yes TagName is declared as unique. it is a table from joomla k2 its how the tags work in there im just trying to import a batch to the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you, my ways is: create two tables first. If you know better way, please let me know.

Table Tag

id   keyword

Table C_Tag

id tag_id user_id

Foreign key Tag(id) Reference C_Tag (tag_id)

```html
<?php
$tag=$_POST['tag_name'] //get the tag name
$current_user=$_POST['users_id'];// get the current user id
include 'db_tag.php';

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT keyword, id FROM Tag WHERE keyword = :tag "); 

$stmt->bindParam(':tag', $tag);
$stmt->execute();
$row_tag = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($row_tag as $row_tag){
}

//if the keyword exist, only update the C_Tag table
if ($row_tag['term'] == $tag){
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t.id, t.keyword, ct.tag_id, ct.user_id FROM Tag t , C_Tag ct WHERE t.id=ct.tag_id  ");
  $stmt->bindValue(':current_id',$current_user);
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $row = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($row as $row){

  }

  $row_id=$row['id'];
  $row_tag_id=$row['tag_id'];
  $row_user_id=$row['user_id'];

  if( $current_user == $row_user_id && $row_id == ! $row_tag_id ){
//make sure same user cannot enter duplicate keyword
$stmt = $db->prepare ("INSERT INTO C_Tag (user_id, tag_id) 
  SELECT :current_id, id 
  FROM tag
  WHERE keyword=:keyword 
");
$stmt->bindValue(':current_id',$current_user);
$stmt->bindValue(':keyword', $tag); 
$stmt->execute(); 
  }
} else {
  //if the keyword is new, I will insert it into both table
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for r time conan, well basicaly u have 2 tables, one holds 

int TagID, varchar TagName

the other table holds

int TagID, Int ItemID;

I have the itemID and also the TagName

but i need the TagID from the Tagname

I managed to make it with multiple queries but it was way slow what i need is a way to speedup this process making it more eficiently.

Answer (score 0):

this appears to be the solution

[How to copy a row and insert in same table with a autoincrement field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156340/how-to-copy-a-row-and-insert-in-same-table-with-a-autoincrement-field-in-mysql)

```
insert into zr1f4_k2_tags_xref (id, tagID, itemID) select NULL, tagID, @itemID from zr1f4_k2_tags where name=@tagName
```

but i cant make it work.

this are the tables

```
zr1f4_k2_tags
id          int(11)
name        varchar(255)
published   smallint(6)

zr1f4_k2_tags_xref
id      int(11)
tagID   int(11)
itemID  int(11)
```

I'm trying to insert the ID of the tag related to the tagname and item ID which ill add explicitly. and the id is autonumeric