# Getting error like Operand should contain 1 column(s), When duplicating a record with some column values changes only required

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code that I have tried to make a duplicate of the record with help of `id`, by keeping the original record with one column value change. I have tried without the `id` also, as it gets auto increment when inserting, but got errors like `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near`.

```
INSERT INTO 
    `org_emps`
    (
        3,
        `admin_id`, 
        `emp_branch_id`, 
        `emp_name`, 
        'ITSe08A 0002', 
        `emp_designation`, 
        `emp_department`, 
        `emp_father_husband`, 
        `emp_mother`, 
        `emp_wife`, 
        `emp_nominee`, 
        '02-03-2018', 
        `emp_dob`, 
        `emp_gender`, 
        `emp_m_status`, 
        `emp_father_husband_dob`, 
        `emp_mother_dob`, 
        `emp_wife_dob`, 
        `emp_nominee_dob`, 
        `emp_aadhar`, 
        `emp_PAN`, 
        `emp_bank_ac_num`, 
        `emp_bank_ifsc`, 
        `emp_bnk_branch_address`, 
        `emp_pf_status`, 
        `emp_esi_status`, 
        `emp_income_tax`, 
        `emp_tds`, 
        `emp_photo`, 
        `emp_addr1`, 
        `emp_addr2`, 
        `emp_phone`, 
        `emp_email`, 
        `emp_w_off`, 
        `emp_ot_rate`, 
        'March 2, 2018, 8:46 am', 
        1, 
        `emp_key`
    ) 
    SELECT (
        `id`, 
        `admin_id`, 
        `emp_branch_id`, 
        `emp_name`, 
        `emp_org_id`, 
        `emp_designation`, 
        `emp_department`, 
        `emp_father_husband`, 
        `emp_mother`, 
        `emp_wife`, 
        `emp_nominee`, 
        `emp_doj`, 
        `emp_dob`, 
        `emp_gender`, 
        `emp_m_status`, 
        `emp_father_husband_dob`, 
        `emp_mother_dob`, 
        `emp_wife_dob`, 
        `emp_nominee_dob`, 
        `emp_aadhar`, 
        `emp_PAN`, 
        `emp_bank_ac_num`, 
        `emp_bank_ifsc`, 
        `emp_bnk_branch_address`, 
        `emp_pf_status`, 
        `emp_esi_status`, 
        `emp_income_tax`, 
        `emp_tds`, 
        `emp_photo`, 
        `emp_addr1`, 
        `emp_addr2`, 
        `emp_phone`, 
        `emp_email`, 
        `emp_w_off`, 
        `emp_ot_rate`, 
        `emp_created_on`,
        `emp_type`, 
        `emp_key`
    ) 
    FROM 
        `org_emps` 
    WHERE 
        id = 2
```

Comment: You do not have a column  `3` in your db

Comment: Add the complete error message

Comment: You seem to be mixing all kinds of stuff a bit randomly. Insert, Select, column names, values etc. The error might say "an error" but there are definitely  more..

Comment: It probably is your date (`'March 2, 2018, 8:46 am'`). Don't think mysql recognizes it as a date format

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson there was not a select in the original question.

Comment: @P.Salmon - Yes there was. In the middle of the one line string. I didn't just randomly add SQL key words... I just added line breaks and tabs.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson aplogies

Comment: Thanks for the replies. There's no issues with date, it is a TEXT type column.

Comment: _"There's no issues with date, it is a TEXT type column"_ - You're still mixing column names and values. Example: in the insert, the first value is `3` and the second value seems to be a column name.

Comment: Okay, Then. How can I add id column value? for duplicating record. Let me know pls.

Comment: Or else, please suggest me an example that how can i make a duplicate record of a row in my table by making them with two or three columns change.

Answer (score 0):

Number of insert columns and their values should be same.Your insert statement column and values columns number are not same here.

Comment: That's only one of several issues with that query.

Comment: What my intention is, I have a employee record of type 0, i just want to make a duplicate and make the original record type column as 3, the new record column type is 1. That's it. If you need more explanation, I will try to give you more.

Comment: column id is auto incremented, is there any need to mention that column also while making duplicate?

Comment: Please, help me to achieve this.. I'm on urgent work requirement.

Comment: And, i have tried id column as it is in both insert and select clauses. but no use of it. it remains same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156340/how-to-copy-a-row-and-insert-in-same-table-with-a-autoincrement-field-in-mysql By this I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

Constants values must be part of the select part:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `org_emps`
    (
        `id`,
       `admin_id`, 
       `emp_branch_id`, 
       `emp_name`, 

...   ) 
    SELECT (
        3, 
      `admin_id`, 
      `emp_branch_id`, 
      `emp_name`, 

   ...
    ) 
    FROM 
        `org_emps` 
    WHERE 
        id = 2
```

Comment: So, What do you say, I did't get. Please help me to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: or else, let me know. How can I duplicate a record in my MySQL db, having id (primary auto increment key of my table) by
1. Keep the original record as it is, with just changing the value of column emp_type.
2. Make a duplicate with auto incremented id, and along with some value changes in couple of columns like emp_doj, emp_type, etc..

Comment: @DaraNaveenKumar read the code snippet and you should see what i mean.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '3,`admin_id`, `emp_branch_id`, `emp_name`, 'ITSe08A 0002', `emp_designation`, `e' at line 1

Comment: Oh!! Okay my dear. Thank you.