# How to Insert new value into table using where

Tags: php, mysql, insert, where-clause

I have one table name "Grade" with this structure:

```
ID  Student_ID First_Name Last_Name Grade
1       1         John      Smith    60
2       2         Garry     Poul     70
3       1         John      Smith    80
```

And I want to add a new grade for `Student_ID = 1` in the table `Grade`, I am using PHP with MySQL DB.

I used this but gives me error!

`$sql = "INSERT INTO Grade (Grade) VALUES ('85') WHERE Student_ID=1 ";`

During search I found that I can't use WHERE with INSERT in MySQL, how can solve it?

Thanks for all

Comment: You want to UPDATE and not INSERT

Comment: This data is denormalised - the student names should be in s separate "students" table, not repeated in this grades table. This table only needs the student ID and grade fields...and maybe a subject ID - otherwise how do you know what the grade was for?

Comment: Anyway are you asking how to add an extra grade for student 1, or alter one of the existing grades? It's not clear, from your wording.

Comment: I want to add a new grade for the Student_ID in the same table.

Comment: `insert into grade ( grade,student_id) values (85,1)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a row and insert in same table with a autoincrement field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156340/how-to-copy-a-row-and-insert-in-same-table-with-a-autoincrement-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

For updating existing records use `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`

```
UPDATE Grade 
SET Grade = 85  
WHERE Student_ID = 1
```

Comment: But will update all ```Student_ID``` values in the table! and I want to add a new value not update

Answer (score -1):

**Insert:**
If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query

**Update**:
when updating records in a table! Notice the WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement. The WHERE clause specifies which record(s) that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records in the table will be updated!

UPDATE Grade
SET Grade = 85
WHERE Student_ID=1 ;

Comment: INSERT does not have a WHERE clause, ever

Comment: `you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query`...you still should though, in case the order changes, or more fields are added in the middle of the list

Comment: But I tried ```UPDATE``` it updated all Student_ID grades not added, I want to add not update.